# How can i create a function using struct to create a condition

Tags: data-structures, struct, conditional-statements, lisp, racket

i am trying to  create a little mini game using racket and structs to creating a story telling game.i have already defined lists and the struct i need to get going but i don't know how to put into a function,for when the function is ran it will allow the user input a parameter corresponding  to A or B and depending on the choice it shall print lists A or B

```
(define A '("Confidently stepped right in to solve the mystery atop Skelen Manor."))
(define b '( "Ran away due to my fear of death and the boredom of the paperwork after the matter"))
(define line1 '("Walking away from the police chatter, I approached the eery-looking Skelen Manor, a relic of an
;older generation; and as I opened the golden doors into the manor, I took a deep breath and"))
(define line2 '("You have failed the case, and let down the department... but worry not! Would you
;like to try again?"))
(define line3 '( "press no the game will CLOSE
or  press Yes the game will restart from the Chapter 1 intro text as typed above"))
;we will use strucure to track the users choices

(struct choice1 ( A b))

(make-string string string)

(define first (choice1 A b))


(define (options choice1)
  (
```

Comment: What language are you using? (what is `struct`?)  What are you using to run your code?

Comment: im using racket,struct is supposed to take instances of choices and the aim is it will use those instances to make decsions based on the choices given,if i chose choice A it will run the line a if i choice line b it will run line b appended with line 2 and 3

Comment: Racket includes many languages: in DrRacket teaching languages can be chosen from the Language menu. There are excellent [free courses](https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/home) using these languages from which "...how to put [ideas] into a function" can be learned. Learning a "[**design method** that enables systematic design of functions](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UBCx+HtC1x+2T2017/77860a93562d40bda45e452ea064998b/#HtDF)" is helpful.